# ConfigurationManager could not be found

Tags: .net, configurationmanager, system.configuration, webconfigurationmanager

I have a website based on react for frontend and .net MVC for the backend

I want to get the AppSettings methode in the `ConfigurationManager`, but VS tells me, that there is no `ConfigurationManager` type name in `System.Configuration`

I have a reference on `System.Configuration`. Everything in other questions i tried, but it won't work.

If I try to acces the AppSettings with the methode `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings` it gives me an error that there is no type name or namespace for `Configuration`

[Full error from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E2yW.png)

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: I believe you need System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings NOT System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Comment: I have tried it, but I can't access the funktion `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` because it cant found `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow...

With nuGet I had to search for `system.configuration` and then i could install `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

Now, it works fine